# Accessing JSON attributes Object Header vs Expanded Form

Tags: json, object, parsing, attributes

Can anyone clarify why some JSON attributes are present in expanded form (when you expand the object or click the drop-down) but not in the header or collapsed versions[image]?

[image]

I can only seem to access the ones in the header. I am wondering why, and furthermore, how to access the ones in expanded form if possible.

Thanks